# Div position - css

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to achieve, that the div's will behave like an example on picture, using css:
[image: page example]

Is there any clean way to do this? I achieve this using javascript to calculate "left" div height and "main" div width and height. But i dont like this solution...is there any way to do this using css only?

Edit:
Page must not have scrollbar...so page's height is always max 100%, and no more...

thanks

Comment: Can we see some of your code?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want?  The layout in your picture can be created very easily, and can reflow/resize in different ways that the picture doesn't illustrate. What's the intended purpose of calculating sizes in JS?

Comment: You want to keep the blue bar always visible even when scrolling?

Comment: I don't know, how to make left div, for an example to resize automaticaly from header to footer...i cant use height: 100%...
I want my page to always look like this, no metter how big is screen...so no hard coded width and height :>

Comment: for an example...header has 40px, footer 20px...fixed! that in some case mean that left div's height need to be 80%...some time 90%...and so on...

Comment: @Klemzy done without scroll bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sidebar (or any other div) is 100% height, and on top you have a 30px header, so that causes your container to be 100% + 30px height.

In the future you will have in css3 calc(): 
http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/css3-calc/
This will solve your problem.

But for now you can add `overflow: hidden;` to the `html` and `body` section, but I recommend calculate the height of the sidebar ( container height - header height) using Javascript.

Check [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/DmHUX/12/)

Comment: yea u see, here is the problem...100% + 30px :) i wish css to do all the work, without  js...:D i have the solution using js, but i wish pure css here :>

Comment: @Klemzy you can add the `overflow:hidden` property to the body and then it will work (but test cross browsers) ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the two-column layout, you do it with pure CSS like this:

```css
.container {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    clear: left;
}

.right {
    margin-left: 100px;
    background-color: #888888;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

**Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xv9xn/)**

The `div` on top can be achieved without any special CSS. To place something below (a footer for example), you'll need to use `clear: both`.

Comment: yes, but here we have scrollbar...i dont want page to scroll...there is my prob.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code it is hard to determine what you want. Here is a extremely simple version of what I believe you want.

HTML:

```
<div id="header">

</div>
<div id="side">

</div>
<div id="content">

</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#header {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
}
#side {
    width:300px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
#content {
    width:660px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/H6a8n/1/)

Comment: yea but here we have hardcoded width and height...there is the problem...i wish that page will be full...content will start beside #side and end at the right end...same with height...i wisht container and side start at bottom of header and end before fotter at bottom of screen-page

Comment: @Klemzy, check my answer, is just add the `overflow:hidden;` to the `body`

Comment: @Klemzy, When I answered your question I missed the part where you talked about no scroll bars. Sorry about that. Adding overflow:hidden to the body like Tom said might fix your problem.